# Auto Scroll iframe on page load

Tags: iframe, scrollbar

i'm opening a website in an iframe (using a bootstrap modal) and
i know that there will be a vertical overflow in that iframe.

Because there is a navigation bar of 200px on the left site on that opened website
i want to auto scroll 200px to the right.

does somebody know how to handle that?

Comment: Could you please explain your problem with some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the iframe in a div with overflow:hidden;

iframe style margin-left:-200px;

Problem solved, do you need an example or is the problem resolved with this answer?

**UPDATE**

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
   <iframe src="http://floradetuinen.nl/" width="900" height="900" style="margin-left:-200px">
</div>
```